# Aurelia CLI and braintree-web

Tags: braintree, aurelia

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/braintree-web with Aurelia (using the aurelia-cli and RequireJS). I am stuck trying to get all the many dependencies to resolve.

To use 3rd party library in Aurelia the library must be defined in the aurelia.json file.

If I add "braintree-web" in that file then aurelia complains that "braintree-web" it requires the modules "american-express", "apple-pay" etc etc.

If I manually create the "american-express", "apple-pay" dependencies then each one also refers to "braintree-web/lib", and a bunch of other sub-directory dependencies.

In short I can't get the "braintree-web" module to load because I have to manually build all sub-dependencies and its too complex to get working.

As I state above, I am using requireJS, should these dependencies all resolve correctly?

Any ideas as to how I can get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all dependencies is what you need, then with requirejs + aurelia-cli you'll have to declare all dependencies. There is an experimental version of the cli being developed which you can find [here](https://github.com/huochunpeng/cli/tree/auto-tracing), where you won't have to declare any dependencies in `aurelia.json` anymore.

With webpack you also don't need to declare any dependencies by the way.

Do you really need everything though? The [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/javascript/v3) mention for example you could import just the client. Still looks like a whole heap of dependencies, but at least a lot less than importing the main index.js.

You could also just include their pre-bundled client which I believe is https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.32.1/js/client.min.js

On a side note, the person developing aforementioned experimental CLI is actually looking for people to test it with non-trivial apps. Me and several others have tried it with great results, so I can recommend you try it. If you could report back in the [PR](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/pull/862) that would be really awesome.

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I go about including the pre-bundled client directly in my code? I need to be able to import the code in my view model so I can call the client. i.e. I need to say "import * as client from X"

Comment: Probably easiest to download the pre-bundled file, and save it under `scripts/braintree-web.3.32.1-client.min.js` or something among those lines. Then just add it to the `prepend` section of your bundles, right before `require.js`. It'll be globally available via the `braintree.` namespace. Installing `@types/braintree-web` as a dev dependency is probably a good idea if you're using typescript.

Comment: Thanks Fred, I'll have a look at that PR too.

Comment: Setup is the same, just checkout the right tag: `git clone https://github.com/huochunpeng/cli aurelia-cli` `git checkout tags/at12` `cd aurelia-cli` `npm install` `npm link` `npm install gulp@^4.0.0 typescript babel-register babel-polyfill` and you're done. Then in project directory `npm link aurelia-cli`